# how to make Jpanel in an array?

Tags: java, jpanel

I don't really like the way the code is written, I know it's written in a bad way, so is there a way to write this in an easier way? Maybe by making an array and loop through?

```
private JPanel pnl1; 
private JPanel pnl2; 
private JPanel pnl3; 
private JPanel pnl4; 
private JPanel pnl5; 

public void createGUI() {
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //Panel related code will go here
    pnl1 = createPanel(Color.blue);
    pnl2 = createPanel(Color.black);
    pnl3 = createPanel(Color.cyan);
    pnl4 = createPanel(Color.green);
    pnl5 = createPanel(Color.darkGray);
    this.getContentPane().add(pnl1, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.getContentPane().add(pnl2, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.getContentPane().add(pnl3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.getContentPane().add(pnl4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(pnl5, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    repaint();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel createPanel(Color c) {
    //Create a JPanel object and store it in a local var
    //set the background colour to that passed in c
    //Return the JPanel object
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setBackground(c);
    return jp;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: To avoid "X-Y" questions you should tell us what you want to achieve. Maybe it makes sense to make an array of these objects. Maybe it doesn't. Right now we don't have enough info to say whether it is a good idea. Is it possible? Sure. Is it recommended? It depends.

Comment: To see what @jdv meant visit [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @Pshemo, thanks. I was being lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely it is possible to rewrite your code using arrays and a loop.

In your `createGUI()` method you could do something like this:

```
Color[] colors = {
        Color.blue, Color.black, Color.cyan, Color.green, Color.darkGray
};
Object[] constraints = {
        BorderLayout.EAST, BorderLayout.WEST, BorderLayout.SOUTH, BorderLayout.CENTER, BorderLayout.NORTH
};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    JPanel panel = createPanel(colors[i]);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel, constraints[i]);
}
```

But as others already commented: Depending on your goal,
this may be or may not be the best idea to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **import java.util.ArrayList;** ?

```
public void createGUI() {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //Panel related code will go here

        ArrayList<JPanel> array = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
            array.add(new JPanel());

            switch(i){
                case 1: this.getContentPane().add(array.get(i).setBackground(Color.blue), BorderLayout.EAST);
                break;
                case 2: this.getContentPane().add(array.get(i).setBackground(Color.black), BorderLayout.WEST);
                break;
                case 3: this.getContentPane().add(array.get(i).setBackground(Color.cyan), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                break;
                case 4: this.getContentPane().add(array.get(i).setBackground(Color.green), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                break;
                case 5: this.getContentPane().add(array.get(i).setBackground(Color.darkGray), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                break;
            }
        }

        repaint();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```